# UI-Bootstrap only apply modal backdrop to element

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

My application shows a UI-Bootstrap modal inside a `div`, above it there is navigation bar, usually when I start the modal the entire background is applied with a backdrop (dimmer), my modal is not appended to `body` but rather to the `div` like so (modal options):

```
appendTo: angular.element(document.querySelector("#mainContent")),
backdrop: true,
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rs6NteOvHYCtbmCAwkCW?p=preview)

`#mainContent` is several levels down the DOM from body, but the entire viewport is dimmed by the backdrop. Is there a way to apply the backdrop (or even the entire modal assembly) to only 1 element instead of the entire viewport?

Comment: not sure how it designed to be done, but since backdrop is just another div - you can modify it css in any way you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the CSS part of the backdrop to this and it will only cover the first parent container that doesn't have position:absolute

```
.modal-backdrop {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1040;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

I have added it on the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jEDY7agrngTMioQacskS?p=preview)

Comment: it works on the plunker but not where i need it, i was kind of hoped to apply it to a div without any constraints

Comment: this principle should work everywhere, you just need to adapt it to your code

Comment: yes off course, you are right. although it's worth mentioning that `.modal-backdrop` would override all other modal styles, it should be named something else and used with `backdropClass` !!